# Angular Firebase Converting Observable to plain object for data usage inside component

Tags: json, angular, typescript, firebase, observable

I'm using angular firestore to pull image references from a Firebase database. I know how to get the observible from the data base and hook it into the template via async, but I want to expose the data to my component to read Oninit(). I've attempted multiple ways of dragging the data out but none have been sucessfull. Code Spinets below

---

product.model.ts

```
export interface Product {
 $key?: string;
 name?: string;
 price?: number;
 condition?: string;
 image?: string;
 mainPic?: string;
}
```

product.component.ts

```
Variables-----
product: Observable<Product>;

Constructor----
----One of the ways I got the firebase document
   this.invoicesCollection = this.afs.collection("/Products");
   this.product = this.getProduct2("test_product");
---Another way I got the firestore document

  this.TED = this.db.getDoc3().subscribe((doc) => this.TED = doc as Product);
-- this is inside a service
 getDoc3() {
   const ref = this.afs.collection("/Products").doc("test_product");
   // return ref.get().subscribe((doc) => this.data = doc as Product);
   return ref.get()
 }

-- yet another way I got the data
 getProduct2(id: string): Observable<Product> {
   //  const productsDocuments = this.afs.doc<Product>("Products/" + id);
   const productsDocuments = this.afs.doc<Product>("Products/test_product");

   return productsDocuments.snapshotChanges().pipe(
     map((changes) => {
       const data = changes.payload.data();
       const id = changes.payload.id;

       return { id, ...data as Product };
     })
   );
 }
```

All of those methods work for retrieving an observable but I can't access the data in the component.

some of my attempts to drag the data out of the observable

```
// console.log(JSON.stringify(this.product as Product))
//console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.product)))

   //     this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe((data) => {
   //     this.products = data.map((e) => {
   //       return {
   //        id: e.payload.doc.id,
   //         ...e.payload.doc.data(),
   //       } as Product;
   //  });

 //  getInvoice() {
 //  var docref = this.afs.collection("/Products").doc(this.invoiceId);
 //   var docref = this.afs.collection("/Products").doc("test");
 //   docref.ref.get().then((doc) => {
 //     if (doc.exists) {
 //       var invoice = doc.data(); // <------WORKS



 // this.invoice = doc.data(); <------DOESN'T WORK
 //       console.log("Invoice data: ", doc.data());
 //    } else {
 //       console.error("No matching invoice found");
 //     }
 //   });
 //  }
```

Where i'm trying to pass my data

```
    this.galleryImages = [
      {
        small: this.product.image,
        medium: this.product.image,
        big: this.product.image,

      },
```

NGX image gallery

```
<div>
  <div class="Home">
    <div class="content">
      <ngx-gallery [options]="galleryOptions" [images]="galleryImages"></ngx-gallery>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. Also let me know if you need more code or a clarification.

Comment: For what reason do you need the data outside the template?

Comment: I'm trying to pass image refrences to ngx gallery. `this.galleryOptions = [


    this.galleryImages = [
      {
        small: this.product.image,
        medium: this.product.image,
        big: this.product.image,

      },`

Comment: is `this.galleryImages` used in the template? can you post it?

Comment: I updated the post to include the html for the gallery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is use streams as far as possible, ideally they are only subscribed to in the template via async pipe.

So you can use a second observable stream to obtain the image information from the product, and pass it to the gallery via an async pipe.

```
product$ = getProduct2(id);
images$ = product$.pipe(map(product => [{
    small: product.image,
    medium: product.image,
    big: product.image,
  }]
));
```

In your template:

```
<ngx-gallery [options]="galleryOptions" [images]="images$ | async"></ngx-gallery>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. =) I didn't even think about directly piping the observable =/. I've spent more time on this than i'd care to admit. thanks for saving me even more time. no worries if you don't have to time to answer but is there a way to directly extract the values for manipulation in the component?

Comment: No problem. Re: using the values in the component, it depends what you want to do with them? You can subscribe to image$ but as above you want to avoid that if you can.